# Ember JsonApi with Jax-Rs content type on Posts

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api, tomee-7

I am using `Ember-Data` clientside and `Tomee7` with `Jax-RS` on the Server.

I would very much like use the Ember-Data's JsonAPIAdapter and adhere to the jsonAPI [specifications](http://jsonapi.org/format/)

If I understand correctly, all HTTP communications [must](http://jsonapi.org/format/#content-negotiation-servers) have the `Content-Type` header set to `application/vnd.api+json`

The Problem when I try to POST something to the Server I get a 415 Unsupported Media error

I've decorated my services like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/vnd.api+json")
@Path("somePostEndPoint")
public Response postService (@FormParam "someData" String someData) {
        //....
}
```

but I am returned:

> An application/x-www-form-urlencoded form request is expected but the
>   request media type is application/vnd.api+json. Consider removing @FormParam annotations

When I make the Request outside of EmberData (with Postman) Everything works fine.

I understand the @FormParam requires `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Could I use something else?

It would be a shame to not get to use the JsonApiAdapter. :(

does anyone have any Ideas what I could try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok a colleague of mine figured it out:

```
@Path("somePostEndPoint")
    @POST
    @Produces(value={"application/vnd.api+json",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes(value={"application/vnd.api+json",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})

    public Response postService (String someData) {
      //...
    }
```

- Do not use `@FormParam`, just set a String. `@FormParam` requires the
  `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- use `@Consumes(value={"application/vnd.api+json",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})`

this worked for us.